# Mutiplication of n functions

Tags: python, function

I want to write a function in Python that returns the multiplication of n functions `(f1(x) * f2(x) * f3(x) * ... * fn(x))`.

I was thinking in something like:

```
def mult_func(*args):
    return lambda x: args(0)(x) * args(1)(x) ...
```

but I don't know exactly how to loop through the `n` functions in args.

Thank you.

Comment: `for func in args: prod *= func(x)`?

Answer (score 6):

Its very simple - just use reduce:

```
from operator import mul    

def mult_func(*args):
    return lambda x: reduce(mul, (n(x) for n in args), 1)
```

That's just a generator expression looping through the functions, and reducing by multiplication.

Comment: Use `operator.mul` instead; there's no guarantee the functions return integers.

Comment: `operator.mul` is far more efficient than the equivalent `lambda` expression; cases like this are why the `operator` modules exposes the operators as functions.

Answer (score 5):

`args` is just a tuple, but it will be difficult to iterate over them the way you need to in a `lambda` expression (unless you use `reduce`). Define a nested function instead.

```
def mult_func(*args):
    def _(x):
        rv = 1
        for func in args:
            rv *= func(x)
        return rv
    return _
```

Comment: Is making a nested function really necessary? Wouldn't it be easier to just keep a running total in a variable while iterating over args?

Comment: Based on the OP's attempts, I thought he was looking for a function that would create a function that computes the product, rather than immediately computing a product for a particular value of `x`. (`f = mult_func(f1, f2, f3); f(3) == f1(3) * f2(3) * f3(3)`)

Answer (score 2):

```
def mult_func(x, *args):
    total = 1
    for func in args:
        total *= func(x)
    return total
```

Very simply returns the product of all `args` with input of `x`.

Quick example:

```
def square(n):
    return n**2

>>> print mult_func(2, square, square) 
16
>>> print mult_func(2, square, square, square)
64
```

Answer (score 0):

It's that time of night, so here's a mutually recursive solution:

```
def multiply_funcs(funcs):
    def inner(x):
        if not funcs:
             return 1
        return funcs[0](x) * multiply_funcs(funcs[1:])(x)
    return inner
```

Comment: Shouldn't it return 1 and not x if funcs is empty...since 1 is the identity of multiplication?

Comment: Also you should use the asterisk syntax since its more flexible. This can be done by replacing funcs with *funcs in the parameter list and replacing (funcs[1:]) with (*funcs[1:]).

Comment: Otherwise, nice solution...but go to bed :)

Comment: I corrected the base case as you were certainly correct, but I disagree that star unpacking is more 'flexible' in this case. It's really just syntactic sugar -- that's to say, i don't get what it buys you since at invocation time, you have to have hardcoded references to functions or unpack a reference to a list of functions.

Comment: Well I guess by flexible I mean more Pythonic, since `multiply_funcs(f, g, h)` is highly preferable over `multiply_funcs((f, g, h))`. Of course if you're passing in iterables of functions, you have to add in an extra asterisk to unpack *but*...come on. I'd rather throw a couple asterisks in my code than have to make lists/tuples just because the function expects them.

Comment: By the way, indexing is not supported by iterables. So in the example of something like multiply_funcs(((lambda x: i*x) for i in range(1, 10))) you're going to have to make an iterator from the argument to handle that. This is more of a criticism of the recursive indexing approach than the parameter style.

Comment: I mean, don't get me wrong, star unpacking's cool and all, but `func(values)` is __always__ more flexible than `func(value, other_value, other_other_value)`, and I find myself way more likely to have a dynamically constructed list that I suddenly have to unnecessarily star unpack because some function thought it was cool to be written that way. Moreover, `func(values)` is explicit that each value is treated the same whereas `func(some_value, other_value, other_other_value)` can easily be misinterpeted. I just don't think this is the appropriate context for star unpacking.

Comment: Though, note, if your function used asterisk syntax, you wouldn't have to worry about generators being passed in, just unpack the generator in the call and they are automatically treated as a tuple. Then you can index away.

Comment: You're of course right about a general iterable; were this at all production code (which, heh, we both know it ain't) I'd probably aim to use `iter/next`.